# Rails 4 multiple SMTP configurations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, smtp, sendgrid, mailgun

My rails 4 application works fine when using `Mailgun` or `Sendgrid`. I want to use both ex. When sending Orders to go through `Sendgrid` and when create Tickets to go through `Mailgun`.

I have both accounts and my `config/environments/development.rb` looks like:

```
 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'smtp.mailgun.org',
    port: 587,
    user_name: 'some_username',
    password: 'some_password',
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true   }
```

If I replace with `Sengrid smtp_settings` it starts sending from `Sendgrid` but as I mentioned I want both and choose which one for specific function.

Thank you

Comment: how you imagine use both services? you mean in difference environments or it simultaneously?

Comment: I mean in diifferent environments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for different environments you can set different email configurations

in `config/environments/staging.rb` one mail service,

in `config/environments/production.rb` second,

and for `config/environments/development.rb` I suggest you to use `letter_opener`

and after that in difference environment modes you will using appropriate mail settings

**EDIT**

**I guess it's bad decision**, but
if you wanna send same mail via two mail services, you can redefine `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings`.

Just create two mailers and redefine settings inside mailer :

first

```
class MailgunUserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      address: 'smtp.mailgun.org',
      port: 587,
      user_name: 'some_username',
      password: 'some_password',
      authentication: 'plain',
      enable_starttls_auto: true   }

  def created(@user)
    .....
```

and second

```
class MandrillUserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      address: 'smtp.mandrill.com',
      port: 587,
      user_name: 'some_username',
      password: 'some_password',
      authentication: 'plain',
      enable_starttls_auto: true   }

  def created(@user)
    .....
```

and than you can send same email via 2 providers:

MailgunUserMailer.created.deliver
MandrillUserMailer.created.deliver

Comment: I have done this but let me explain again. In both `staging`, `production` and `development` I want to use both `Mailgun` and `Sendgrid` and use them ex. send_order(with mailgun) and send_ticket(with sendgrid).

Comment: Sobchuk how to create two mailers and redefine settings ? thank you